# tearDown() that is only executed after ALL tests have run?

Tags: nodeunit, knex.js

I'm trying to write some integration tests in NodeUnit. My tests work fine, but the test runner hangs because [knex](http://knexjs.org) is keeping a PostgreSQL DB connection open.

I can get it to release by calling `knex.destroy()` in my `tearDown`, but unfortunately then the DB is no longer available for the rest of my test suite (and tests in other files as well).

Is there a way to implement a `tearDown` that runs only once, after ALL tests have run?

Comment: I don't have an answer for this specific question, but I upvoted because `knex.destroy()` fixed an issue I was having with gulp hanging. A lot of test frameworks have a before and after method - does NodeUnit not?